# Автоматический приём звонка в Android

Tags: java, android

Каким образом в приложении (дайлер) можно автоматически отвечать на входящие звонки? Нахожу везде только методы индикации звонка.

Ниже код, который умеет автоматически сбрасывать (`endCall()`), но почему-то функция `answerRingingCall()` не хочет работать.

```
try {
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(manager);
    telephony.endCall();
} catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("",e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, для `answerRingingCall()` должен быть декларирован пермишен: `android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: это уже, ессесно, сделано

Comment: вообще уже нашел информацию о том, что начиная с android 2.3.3 этот метод уже не актуален
потому вопрос все еще открыт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось:

```
try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                                Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop